# I have a jmx file where i have written selenium code with javascript. I am unable to run it in EC2 using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmx file where i have written selenium code with javascript. I am unable to run it in EC2 using JMeter.

Here is the error message.

```
unknown error chrome failed to start exited abnormally
```

[Chrome failed to start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onfEQ.png)

Comment: Check whether you are using latest version on JMeter and Chromedriver. Also check for the chrome browser version. Latest version of Chromedriver supports v56-58 chrome browser. Also, make sure that in EC2, you have all the setup. Also uninstalling chrome and reinstalling works in some instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the log file it appears you're using ChromeDriver 2.20. It is quite an outdated version which supports Chrome (or Chromium) versions 43-48.

If you are using a newer Chrome - you have 2 options:

1. Upgrade to ChromeDriver 2.29 which supports Chrome versions 56-58
2. Downgrade your Chrome browser to version 43-48

References:

- [ChromeDriver Release Notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/notes.txt)
- [Getting started with ChromeDriver on Desktop](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you don't have neither Chrome nor specific Chromedriver on your EC2 machine.

For the latter, get it [there](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.29/), then you're going to set system property `webdriver.chrome.driver` to the path to your driver (including the executable name).

As for installing conventional chrome on that GUI-less machine - I'm quite not sure it's going to work, but you may try.

Although the package is anyway out of standard AWS package repositories, so you'd be driven to do that manually from local package.

Let me know if that helped, please.